# Create table in Athena that contains only file names stored in a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have bucket that contains pickled files, I would like to get names of all files to be able to join and get data from another table. When I tried to create an external table, Athena expects columns, but I don't have any.
Is it possible or I am not approaching the task correctly?
Thank you!